# Send data to php page

Tags: php, android, mysql, sqlite

I use this in android service inside handler thread to send data to the php page for inserting into mysql database , the url is ok but for some reason it does not get posted to the php page .url is defined as Public String on the begining of the class .

```
public void onCreate() {
super.onCreate();

// final String mojsadrzaj=new String();

Toast.makeText(this,"Service created ...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



    final SQLiteDatabase db=openOrCreateDatabase("TruckMe", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    db.execSQL("create table if not exists lokacije (id INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, lokacija VARCHAR(600));");

    //regulisanje podataka za logovanje samo prvi put


    String idvozaca=new String();
    db.execSQL("create table if not exists vozac (id INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, idvozaca VARCHAR(15));");
    Cursor d=db.rawQuery("select idvozaca from vozac", null);
    //db.execSQL("delete from vozac;");

    if(d.getCount() > 0)
    {
        d.moveToLast();
        idvozaca=d.getString(d.getColumnIndex("idvozaca"));
        mojsadrzaj=idvozaca;
        Toast t=Toast.makeText(this, "Id vozaca je : " + mojsadrzaj, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        t.show();
        db.close();

    }





    //regulisanje podataka za logovanje samo prvi put

    final Time t=new Time();

    //Toast.makeText(this,"Stao kod upita" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     //deo za thread

     final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                if(indikator != 0)
                {
                try {

                    URL myURL = new URL(url);

                    URLConnection myURLConnection = myURL.openConnection();
                    myURLConnection.connect();
                    Toast.makeText(MyService.this,"saljem na net "+url , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } 
                catch (MalformedURLException e) { 
                    // new URL() failed
                    // ...
                } 
                catch (IOException e) {   
                    // openConnection() failed
                    // ...
                }



                }
                indikator=1;
                handler.postDelayed(this, 9000);

            }
        };


    //b.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);


    //deo koji naknadno ubacujem za kriterijum
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);



    //kraj dela koji sam naknadno ubacio

final   LocationManager m=(LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    //deo koji sam takodje ubacio naknadno
String locationprovider =m.getBestProvider(criteria,true);
//deo koji sam takodje ubacio naknadno kraj


        LocationListener l=new LocationListener() {


                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {


                    String zauzetost=new String();
                    zauzetost="ZAUZET";

                    String format="MM/dd/yyyy";
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format,Locale.US);
                    String date= sdf.format(new Date());


                t.setToNow();   


                String longitude=new String();
                String latitude=new String();
                String speed=new String();

                if((int)arg0.getSpeed()==0)
                {
                    speed="0";
                }
                else
                {
                speed=""+(((int)arg0.getSpeed()*3600)/1000);
                }
                longitude=""+  arg0.getLongitude();
                latitude=""+ arg0.getLatitude();

                Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();



                url="http://www.compensatemeonline.com/truckmeonline/TruckMeOnline/UnosLokacijaSaTelefona.php?id="+mojsadrzaj+"&longitude="+longitude+"&latitude="+latitude+"&brzina="+speed+"&vreme="+cal.getTime()+"&datum="+date+"&zauzetost="+zauzetost;    


                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

            };


            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //pozivanje threada
             runnable.run();
            //pozivanje threada
            m.requestLocationUpdates(locationprovider, 6000, 0, l);

    //      zamenio sam m.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 120000, 0, l); sa m.requestLocationUpdates(locationprovider, 120000, 0, l);
        }
```

All of this works fine when done from activity and posted to php page using webview . But since I cannot use webview from service I use URL...,The link that is toasted after the url is called is fine .What is wrong with this.

Comment: As an aside, services run on the main thread by default, so you want to move the db and networking operations to a seperate thread.

Comment: It is ok for performance but it is not the main issue . Why is my php page not executed ?

Comment: I see that you open the connection, but don't get the an outputStream and write anything to it. The HttpClient class is probably better suited for your needs if you just need to do a simple post.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html under the "Posting Content" section is an example of getting an outputstream to the connection and writing to it.

Comment: But I just want to call a page and I do it with  myURLConnection.connect(); I do not need the content of the page since it is only a php-mysql insert of the location to the database - which is read latter on .

Comment: The URLConnection is pretty much a socket, to be written to a read from a stream. I know you don't need to get the contents of it so you wouldn't get an inputStream to read from. It would be easier to just use an HttpClient execute a simple HTTPPost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with this

```
try {

                    URL myURL = new URL(url);

                    URLConnection myURLConnection = myURL.openConnection();
                    myURLConnection.connect();

                    //
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            myURLConnection.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
    System.out.println(inputLine);
in.close();


                    //
                    Toast.makeText(MyService.this,"saljem na net "+url , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } 
                catch (MalformedURLException e) { 
                    // new URL() failed
                    // ...
                } 
                catch (IOException e) {   
                    // openConnection() failed
                    // ...
                }
```

Comment: What I have noticed is that the size of the size of website link string is the one that makes problems!

Comment: The main problem was that I had some space signs in the link ,after removing them it works ok!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a URLConnection, contruct an `HttpClient` object, to execute an `HttpPost` which is constructed using your target url. Jeff Vogella has a really good example in section 2.3 here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/ApacheHttpClient/article.html

Comment: Using that approach I get an error 02-15 21:01:00.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1880): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 154: http://www.compensatemeonline.com/truckmeonline/TruckMeOnline/UnosLokacijaSaTelefona.php?id=16&longitude=-122.084095&latitude=37.422005&brzina=0&vreme=Fri Feb 15 21:00:56 GMT 2013&datum=02/15/2013&zauzetost=ZAUZET

      }

Comment: and my service cracks ...I already used this several times with success in activities do not know what is the problem now.Maybe I should change & sign in link with some special letters (this is not needed when you use URL approach).